# How to display Current lat long in ios?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

Right now i am using `MapKit` in my application.
i am getting lat long from web service but when i display in `MapKit` i am not getting lat long in `MaKit` in zoom.
can you please tell me what is exact problem.

problem is in attachment[image: you can see my location is not zoom]

and here is my code

```
location.latitude =[lat floatValue];
 location.longitude =[lontd floatValue];
 CLLocationCoordinate2D cord= CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([lat floatValue],[lontd floatValue]);


MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
[annotation setCoordinate:cord];
[annotation setTitle:@"My Place"];
[[self mapkit] addAnnotation:annotation];

//
    MKCoordinateRegion region =
       MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance (
                                        location, 2000, 2000);
       [mapkit setRegion:region animated:NO];
```

can you please tell me why my pin is not zoom to lat long?

Comment: can you please show us Lat long that you get from Service ?

Comment: Try changing span property of map, that will do what you need.

Comment: have u used this method to get current latitude & longitude CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocation

Comment: yes i am using  location.latitude =[lat floatValue];
    location.longitude =[lontd floatValue];
       CLLocationCoordinate2D cord= CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([lat floatValue],[lontd floatValue]);

Comment: my lat long is 6.1596  6.7631

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the application on real device.The Simulator will always show you the default value for Latitude and Longitude.Make sure that the location services are enabled on your device.

Use this method to get current latitude & longitude

-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocation
{

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
return coordinate;
```

}